# Struts 2 how to run a validation before every action

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

In a Struts 2 application, I want to run a logic before **all** project actions. The logic will generate a field error or let the action continue.

I tried to develop an interceptor for this case.

But here is my problem:

In a validator we call `addFieldError(fieldName, object);` to set field error, but I don't know how can I add field errors in an interceptor.

---

If that is not possible, please let me know if I can use a validator which runs before all my actions ( I use `@Validations`, and I am looking for a way not to copy a my validator on top of all my actions! )

Comment: The validation runs *always* before any action. Sometimes you don't need such validations or validations doesn't perform in the transaction so have move to higher layer means a *presentation* layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add field (and action) errors by casting the action invocation to [`ValidationAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html) in your interceptor.
Obviously your action has to actually implement the `ValidationAware` interface, but it probaly does (e.g if your action extends `ActionSupport` then it's also `ValidationAware` because `ActionSupport` implements `ValidationAware`):

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Object action = invocation.getAction();
    if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
        ValidationAware validationAware = (ValidationAware) action;
        validationAware.addFieldError("field", "field error");
        validationAware.addActionMessage("action message");
        validationAware.addActionError("action error");
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `addFieldError()` on the action simply casting it to the `ValidationAware` interface:

```java
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    ActionContext invocationContext = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    Object action = invocation.getAction();

    if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
        ValidationAware va = (ValidationAware) action;
        va.addFieldError("field", "message");
    }

    ....
}
```